# Mesh Circuit Analysis With Constant Current Source

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

[image]

Can anybody tell why the current Is1 from the constant current source not divide at the nodes and will only stay in the loop (in which Ii circle is drawn).

Comment: Hint:  It does not.

Comment: @amateurAstro http://www.solved-problems.com/circuits/electrical-circuits-problems/resistive-circuits/1438/mesh-current-analysis-problem/ but this site says it does

Comment: I think the mistake in your interpretation is because in the mesh current method you solve for currents in each mesh and then you have to superpose them to find the final current. So the defined current $Is_1$ is only a mathematical tool, when there is other currents, it is only a fraction of the total current.

Comment: @Bhavay, The site you gave says that $I_{S1}=I_1$. That is true. There is a difference between node currents and loop currents.

Comment: We are not allowed to answer homework problems here, and comments are not for asking or answering questions. I suggest you first use Kirchoff's current and voltage laws for solving the original problem, and the question you posed in the comment. As @HenriqueLa suggested, the loop current technique sometimes is simpler, but you need to combine them properly to obtain currents through each element. For example, $I_{R1} = I_1 - I_2$.

Answer (score 0):

It does divide, that's why in the mesh current method, when a branch is associated with 2 meshes you have to superimpose them to obtain the actual current.